# Unit test $httpBackend with query params

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, httpbackend

Using `$httpBackend`, how can I use `expectGET` with a url that has query params? The order doesn't matter, and the value doesn't matter.

```
$httpBackend
  .expectGET('/api/my_endpoint/example?X=false&Y=someethingelse&Z=anotherthing')
  .respond(200, {});
```

Using `$resource` this is how I declare it:

```
  get: {
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/api/my_endpoint/example',
      params: {
        X: '@X',
        Y: '@Y',
        Z: '@Z',
      }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003963/httpbackend-with-request-with-query-param/32004266?noredirect=1#comment51911672_32004266 may help

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a regular expression instead of a string for the url parameter. So

```
$httpBackend
    .expectGET(/\/api\/my_endpoint\/example.*/)
    .respond(200, {});
```

If it gets more complex a function can also be set.